# How to access order meta_data with WooCommerce new HPOS DB structure

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm having trouble accessing meta data in the new WooCommerce HPOS wc_orders_meta table. Previously all order details where saved in wp_posts & wp_postmeta, I could just grab meta values using

`get_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_post_meta_name', true );` but this is now not available using the new DB tables.

I can create the custom order meta_data using

`

```
$order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
$order_id = $order->get_id();
$order->update_meta_data( '_tracking', '12345678' );
$order->save();
```

`

I can see the meta data exists using `print_r($order)`

[2] => WC_Meta_Data Object ( [current_data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 3002 [key] => _tracking [value] => 12345678 )

I need to be able to get the custom meta_data using PHP. I've tried using the below code to access it but it returns a null value.

`

```
$order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

     foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $order_meta_value = $item->get_meta( '_tracking', true );
     }

echo $order_meta_value;
```

`

I'm not sure how to move forward?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh a good nights rest and it's simple

```
$tracking = $order->get_meta( '_tracking', true );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).